# void* in malloc vs operator new

Tags: c++

Today I was writing a little Memory Profiler for my code and for the first time overloaded `operator new`. In doing so, I figured the syntax is `void* operator new(size_t sz)`. This is indeed very similar to `malloc` where you have `void* malloc(size_t sz)`.

This got me into thinking since when you use `malloc`, you need to explicitly cast the pointer  back to your data type whereas for new you don't need to do this. How does the compiler figure out the correct data type for `new` and why do you *have* to make it return `void *`? Isn't `T* operator new(size_t sz)` more intuitive?

Comment: In C you don't have to cast the return value of `malloc()`. In fact casting is, at best, redundant and may hide an error the compiler would have caught in the absence of the cast.

Comment: @pmg, chill out, the question shouldn't have really been tagged with `C`

Comment: remember to `free` the data allocated by `new`

Comment: @pmg but if I don't cast, I cannot dereference it!

Comment: @GradGuy: **THIS IS FOR C** you don't ever need to dereference the return value from `malloc()`. Usually you assign that value (of type `void*`) to a pointer to a specific type and then dereference that pointer (of type `specific type *`) **I HAVE NO IDEA HOW `malloc()` WORKS IN C++**.

Comment: @pmg Yeah. That's what I meant! I do `T* ptr = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T))` and so that's what I meant by casting the `malloc` return.

Comment: The cast is, at best, redundant and may hide an error the **C** compiler would have caught ... do `T *ptr = malloc(42 * sizeof *ptr);` to assign to `ptr` a memory address capable of holding 42 objects of type `T`. And remember to `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: @pmg um, ok! I don't follow what "do `T* ptr = malloc(42 * sizeof *ptr);`" means! [this was before edit]

Comment: In C, don't cast the return value of `malloc()`. It is, at best, redundant and may hide an error ...

Comment: @pmg wow! I did not know you can actually do that in `C`! Do you know why `g++` does not like it though? Thanks for the info :)

Comment: @pmg why do you keep repeating the same wrong information? you'll get warnings in any compiler ever if you don't cast the return of malloc

Comment: @OrgnlDave Not in `C` compilers. `C++` compilers won't compile at all.

Comment: @OrgnlDave: in C `void*` (pointers to void) are compatible with pointers to any type of object (*functions are not objects*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ separates memory allocation and object construction. The allocation function (i.e. `operator new()`) returns a `void *` to some *memory*, and the `new` *operator* constructs an object in that memory. If you will, the `new` operator "converts" memory into an object, and a placement-`new` expression is a bit like a "cast":

```
void * addr = ::operator new(sizeof(Foo));    // memory

Foo * p = ::new (addr) Foo(1, true, 'a');     // object (note: no cast!)

p->~Foo();                                    // it's almost over

::operator delete(addr);                      // now it's over!
```

The default, non-placement form of `new` performs allocation and construction in one go. It's morally equivalent to the first half of this example. But still, allocation and construction remain two distinct concepts.

Comment: Can you please explain the difference between " `operator new()` " and the " `new` operator ". Are these two different things? Also, what does second line, `Foo * p = ::new (addr) Foo(1, true, 'a');`, mean?

Comment: Yes, they're different. The first is a function. The second is a language construct that forms a "`new` expression". The value of a `new` expression is a pointer to a freshly constructed object. The first line of the example calls the allocation function; the second involves a `new` expression (in placement form). It is only when you write a *default* new expression that the allocation function gets called automatically, and the allocation function is the only thing you're allowed to replace (or overload per class).

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of that :)

Answer (score 7):

The `operator new` function does not return a `T*` since the returned value does not point to a `T` but just to arbitrary junk. It's not until the constructor is called that you have a pointer to a class instance.

Comment: I'd like to add that the operator new function does in fact call that constructor, registers the destructor for when it comes time to delete, and that all of it can be overloaded if you want to do your own memory management (i.e. for garbage collection)

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between `operator new` and the new operator. The latter creates objects of a given type, the former just allocates memory. The new operator calls `operator new` for the type being created, or, if no version is defined for the required type, uses the global `operator new`. You can't return a `T*` from the `operator new` function as that would be pointing to an object that hasn't been created yet. The object is only created once the constructor has run (and any housekeeping such as vtable creation ,RTTI information, etc).

Don't forget that you can override `operator new` for any class and change it's behviour - it does not need to actually allocate any memory, it just has to return a pointer to some memory. That memory could be from a pre-allocated chunk for example.

Answer (score 1):

`operator new` is a user-overridable run-time support function for the `new` operator, which just provides the service of allocating a suitably aligned and sized block of memory. This function is not the `new` operator itself; you are not rewriting the `new` operator itself when you override this function, but only replacing the allocation service. The `new` operator can be thought of as a syntactic sugar which compiles into a call to its helper, `operator new`, to get the memory, plus constructor calls to initialize it, if required.